# Spring mvc: HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users/photo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editUser(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                             Principal principal) {
    // code never gets here
}
```

my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

form itself:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file"
        name="file"
        />
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
</form>
```

This is what browser says:

[image: http 400]

How to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use this

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="**org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver**" />
```

instead of

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">
```

Comment: Great, this helps (if I remove **'s). But how do you know that I should do this sort of trick?

Comment: I had the same kind of problems

Comment: Great man It was very useful, I wasted a whole day on this trying different things.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet 3.0 specification.

StandardServletMultipartResolver is Standard implementation of the {@link MultipartResolver} interface

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/4.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardServletMultipartResolver.java#StandardServletMultipartResolver